# How could I designate a value, of which I could say that values above said value are greater than the others by a certain percent-data right skewed

Tags: statistical-significance, standard-deviation, skewness, z-score

Essentially I have 38 data points who have all been assigned a score that indicates how likely it is that this spatial point is going to be impacted by a natural disaster. I want to numerically differentiate the values from one another to make a recommendation on which schools are most likely to be affected. I initially thought z-scores would be effective but as the data is right skewed, this is not the case. I feel "log"ing the data would also cause it to lose the information I require from it, to my understanding. Essentially I want to be able to say any values greater than X are in the top Y% of the data.

Comment: the designated value you're talking about is commonly called a threshold value. since you said "in the top Y%", consider quantiles/percentiles of a distribution

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have $n = 1000$ observations from a population with the right-skewed
distribution $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=3, \mathrm{rate} = 0.1),$ which has
$\mu = 30,$ $\sigma^2 = 300,$ $\sigma = 17.321.$ Such a sample is found in R as follows:

```
set.seed(1213)
x = rgamma(1000, 3, .1)
summary(x);  sd(x)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
  0.9446  17.1287  27.7315  30.7203  40.8742 113.4624 
[1] 17.56195    # sample SD
```

If you want a value $q = 55.81$ above which the top 10% of the sample lies, that is
the 90th percentile of the data as found in R. [Various computer programs have different rules for finding percentiles; differences are negligible for samples as large as $n = 1000.$ When the data in `x` are sorted, we find that relevant order statistics are $X_{(899)}=55.444,$ $X_{(900)}=55.806,$ and $X_{(901)}=55.849,$ to three places.]

```
quantile(x, .9)
    90% 
55.8105 
mean(x > 55.81)
[1] 0.1
sort(x)[899:901]
[1] 55.44389 55.80618 55.84939
```

The 90th percentile $53.2232$ of the population, below which 90% of the probability lies. We can say that the sample percentile 55.81 (based on a sample of 1000) is an estimate of the population percentile 53.22.

```
qgamma(.9, 3, .1)
[1] 53.2232
pgamma(53.2232, 3, .1)
[1] 0.9
```

The figure below shows a histogram of the sample along with the density function
of the population. The 90th sample percentile is at the vertical solid blue line and the
90th population percentile is at the vertical dotted line.

[image]

```
hist(x, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", main="n = 1000: GAMMA(3, .1)")
curve(dgamma(x, 3, .1), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
abline(v = 55.81, lwd=2, col="blue")
abline(v = 53.2232, lwd=2, col="brown", lty="dotted")
```

*Note:* For a sample of size $n = 38$ from this distribution, the 90th sample percentile (below, $43.69)$ will not usually be
quite such a good estimate of the 90th population percentile 53.2232 as with the larger sample above.

```
set.seed(2020)
y = rgamma(38, 3, .1)
quantile(y, .9)
     90% 
43.68595 
sort(y)[34:35]
[1] 42.05368 47.49459
```

Comment: Does the sample percentile belong to the empirical distribution (histogram), whereas the population percentile belongs to the parametric distribution? Why do the sample and population both have the same number of observations here?

Comment: There infinitely many potential population values. When using R random sample functions such as `rgamma` you can specify the a desired sample size. The sample percentile is derived from the (empirical) sample at hand. The population percentile is a property of the population distribution. In my example, the population distribution was assumed to be $\mathsf{Gamma}(3, 0.1),$ but in a practical application the population distribution may not be known. You might _estimate_ a population percentile by finding the corresponding percentile of your sample.

Comment: If a university wants to admit only students who score in the top 20% on the ABC Admission Exam, they might look at data from the ABC exam for the last few years to find the score that has corresponded to the 80th percentile historically, and then publish that score for the guidance of this year's potential applicants.

Comment: Right, by parametric distribution I do mean the $\mathsf{Gamma}(3, 0.1)$, which is a parametric distribution, not an empirical one.  Now how accurate is it to clump "quantile threshold", "tail distribution" and "survival function" altogether as descriptors of the same exercise you demonstrated in code? Aren't these three terms highly inter-related if not the same

Comment: Informally speaking: 80th percentile is quantile .8, you can call it a _threshold_ for some purpose if you like. The right tail distribution might be the distribution of the values above some quantile. If the CDF $F_X(k) = P(X\le k) = 0.8,$  then the corresponding k-value is quantile .8. The quantile function is the inverse of the CDF. The survival function is sometimes defined as $G_X(k) = 1 - F_X(k) = P(X > k).$ All related topics but be careful to check the exact definition of each one.

Comment: How to map/locate the 0.8 quantile from the inverse CDF back to the PDF of the same dataset? Or is it just the same location on the real number line for both. Given that skewness is visible on the PDF, not the CDF or its inverse